# Subtracting Rows in SAS Ent Guide

Tags: sas, query-builder, enterprise-guide

I have the following data set:

```
Row   - Customer    - Renew Date     - Type of Renewal     - Days  
 1       - A        - June 10, 2010        - X                        
 2       - A        - May 01, 2011         - Y  
 3       - B        - Jan 05, 2010         - Y  
 4       - B        - Dec 10, 2010         - Z   
 5       - B        - Dec 10, 2011         - X
```

Is there a way I can put a condition in query builder where it subtracts row 1 from row 2 for each customer, so that I can have the # of "Days" after which a customer renew's their membership ?
Basically, I need help in subtracting rows in query builder.
Please adivse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't too hard if you write a datastep.  I don't know that it's easily done in Query Builder.

```
data have;
informat renew_date ANYDTDTE.;
format renew_date DATE9.;
infile datalines dlm='-';
input Row Customer $ Renew_Date  Renewal_Type $;
datalines;
 1       - A        - June 10, 2010        - X                        
 2       - A        - May 01, 2011         - Y  
 3       - B        - Jan 05, 2010         - Y  
 4       - B        - Dec 10, 2010         - Z   
 5       - B        - Dec 10, 2011         - X    
 ;;;;
 run;

 data want;
 set have;
 by customer;
 retain prev_days;  *retain the value of prev_days from one row to the next;
 if first.customer then days_since=0; *initialize days_since to zero for each customer's first record;
 else days_since=renew_date-prev_days; *otherwise set it to the difference;
 output;    *output the current record;
 prev_days=renew_date; *now change prev_days to the renewal date so the next record has it;
 run;
```

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks. But it will also be good to know if this can be done somehow in query builder as well.

Comment: I strongly advise against considering Query Builder a tool for anything other than brief queries - it's not really meant to do anything complicated.  It's basically there for when you have that "Hmm, that data is interesting, I wonder if there is anything like ..." moment while looking at the data but don't want to be bothered to write the data step code.

Comment: +1 @ Joe. Furthermore, Query builder is also hard to reuse. If you spend 20 mins clicking your way to a great query and want to apply it to a different table, you're stuck. By writing code (SQL or data step) it's trivial to apply to a new input data set.

Comment: quick question..... I have to add another column which has a sno. starting from zero. Presently I am doing it using two separate data sets. Can I just combine it in one ? This is what I wrote.------- data want1;
 set have;
 by customer;
 retain prev_renewal;
 if first.customer then prev_renewal=0; 
 else prev_renewal=prev_renewal+1; 
 output; 
 run;     Is there a way I can add this query to the query above.

Comment: Please ask that as a new question, it's too hard to answer questions in comments.